# Where are the controller_manager logs

Tags: ros, ros2, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'am trying to use ros2 controllers on gazebo, yet without sucess.

When launching the  joint_trajectory_controller :

```
ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_trajectory_controller
```

I have an error :

```
[ros2-2] Error loading controller, check controller_manager logs
[ERROR] [ros2-2]: process has died [pid 30159, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_trajectory_controller'].
```

Do you know where I can find the  "controller_manager" logs on ros2 humble?

Error loading controller, check controller_manager logs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410400/where-are-the-controller_manager-logs/) by [Luczia](https://answers.ros.org/users/14356/luczia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the logs in the terminal, in which you launched the controller manager.

So in case of the ign_ros2_control repository (https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control), if you launch the demo "cart_example_position.launch.py" for example, the controller manager logs will be in the terminal, where you launched this demo.

---

Originally posted by [Jariba](https://answers.ros.org/users/133879/jariba/) with karma: 26 on 2023-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonst](https://answers.ros.org/users/136181/jonst/) on 2023-02-01**:
Same problem here - looked in recommended location but did not find a log, is there a filename pattern or extension I can search for (e.g. .log)?

Also is there some way to get the verbose output to the terminal instead of just to log?

**Comment by [Luczia](https://answers.ros.org/users/14356/luczia/) on 2023-05-31**:
Yeah, it is pretty subtle as the logs are sometimes just one line, but the terminal with which I launched the controller_manager has a a "log" info, usually starting with :

[ERROR] [1685575141.283231272] [controller_manager]: